# how can you select the first 5 students in a table according to marks

Tags: sql, python-3.x

```
cursor.execute("select name,marks from student order by marks desc limit 5")
```

> cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

How do I solve this error? is there any other way I can restate the query?
what is wrong with this query?

Comment: Hi guy, `students` or `student` table name?

Answer (score 0):

`limit` isn't part of Oracle's SQL syntax. You can use the `fetch first` instead for such usecases:

```py
cursor.execute("select name, marks from student order by marks desc fetch first 5 rows only")
```

Comment: cursor.execute("select count(*) from student order by marks desc fetch first 5 rows only")
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended       :(((

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle 12C, you can use `fetch`.  In earlier versions, use a subquery and `rownum`:

```
select s.*
from (select s.name, s.marks
      from student s
      order by s.marks desc
     ) s
where rownum <= 5;
```